# .net core c# decrypt base64 string with RSACryptoServiceProvider using string private key

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Im working on an app that will need to decrypt a string that will be encrypted in java using the RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding cypher.

My app will be in c# .

The private keys that am using here are an example.

Im trying to use RSACryptoServiceProvider to decrypt the string but i allways this error:

**'Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Incorrect parameter'
.'**

Code:

```
// encrypted string result is hello
const string encryptedString = "HhB77zNHCiB/CWa8v5VcaUNdi/M/mE9us8mQ4be1o2f3G/rQpsAcD8aue4QRJsOliekHIqaI9vrkyyLIDTJQDbkb15rweHZwwUr0YFqHFAq/PMt9tBph2U7n9zZN0zVDiFP/J4J8FZBGsLFx432YQP7DEi62fbHYY8fm1lXLx/Q=";
const string privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>utm7gcfK7JCTi1gRIcz2/BjtOpAAjqvd0uMKd2AAzxgFCEKCraPNKFjKv5OaEGq6bnbgt2BGx/5m5CrgjR26FMeA924QBoYZodGoSBV4klcoVihXtznWv96FYmuMya+BX5Q5fqM6TJ3iJbXI3+/o5eyblXj/mjjZ+yKGQjUn6Wc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>9+F18Oi6wKgCp4vSySDjKQmzIajs+QPsiOscmZxk/QV9T1Tg+QSi3s3sLxQFGnCU8Q0OE9d4idv6TLtS/ibl1w==</P><Q>wPiE2XzmTsEkOGO6KFfNHqkeh6uwd/WxHcRQgUfhFefl30YtIh1fj+Zq+b/rmzpkPPIVdl6zUbrWeldsfj2G8Q==</Q><DP>LyV52j1Zr+UExDtK9yhDLH4EzSUlFWPSrGQTh4AAkUNnBxy8wYBJPhlqj7W+Fr5NBeAWyl1UNtxZKhkC+wYI9w==</DP><DQ>ipw4uQxpVhqQDN09o6rl0OdD4commRRnY+1WsnZSLO0FBmsfEkktEm09XCZKc5bu14RAfGUrw0JEu14+tTM20Q==</DQ><InverseQ>7KvNQ83Bl1OFVOs4NZt2rFvPFQjSfSEdStyglsABSyBQUpC5IoJsj1SXrXQPPOFDgdDBXXsfJJRHEAl125CTmA==</InverseQ><D>UQkzODL1QCnnw4w7SeSBzY3l/PsNMtM5DkgnduRtFWP+crmdwT8EMBZqQDH8pFgVaOknxn/70qrz5srtvmYBGFjHdVRqBz01huykyIzxYhKATiljp+Akf72ljpIfs4zJ5bIQyA9OMYZKoIUjiUlCKBX29baxJ6tNAObOrwgAyGE=</D></RSAKeyValue>";
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
{
    try
    {
        var base64Encrypted = encryptedString;

        // server decrypting data with private key                    
        rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);

        var resultBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encrypted);
        var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(resultBytes, false);
        var decryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(decryptedData.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    }
}
```

Im using a public website to convert my private key to xml:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Result:

```
 <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>utm7gcfK7JCTi1gRIcz2/BjtOpAAjqvd0uMKd2AAzxgFCEKCraPNKFjKv5OaEGq6bnbgt2BGx/5m5CrgjR26FMeA924QBoYZodGoSBV4klcoVihXtznWv96FYmuMya+BX5Q5fqM6TJ3iJbXI3+/o5eyblXj/mjjZ+yKGQjUn6Wc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>9+F18Oi6wKgCp4vSySDjKQmzIajs+QPsiOscmZxk/QV9T1Tg+QSi3s3sLxQFGnCU8Q0OE9d4idv6TLtS/ibl1w==</P><Q>wPiE2XzmTsEkOGO6KFfNHqkeh6uwd/WxHcRQgUfhFefl30YtIh1fj+Zq+b/rmzpkPPIVdl6zUbrWeldsfj2G8Q==</Q><DP>LyV52j1Zr+UExDtK9yhDLH4EzSUlFWPSrGQTh4AAkUNnBxy8wYBJPhlqj7W+Fr5NBeAWyl1UNtxZKhkC+wYI9w==</DP><DQ>ipw4uQxpVhqQDN09o6rl0OdD4commRRnY+1WsnZSLO0FBmsfEkktEm09XCZKc5bu14RAfGUrw0JEu14+tTM20Q==</DQ><InverseQ>7KvNQ83Bl1OFVOs4NZt2rFvPFQjSfSEdStyglsABSyBQUpC5IoJsj1SXrXQPPOFDgdDBXXsfJJRHEAl125CTmA==</InverseQ><D>UQkzODL1QCnnw4w7SeSBzY3l/PsNMtM5DkgnduRtFWP+crmdwT8EMBZqQDH8pFgVaOknxn/70qrz5srtvmYBGFjHdVRqBz01huykyIzxYhKATiljp+Akf72ljpIfs4zJ5bIQyA9OMYZKoIUjiUlCKBX29baxJ6tNAObOrwgAyGE=</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

But i still face this error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You private key has the tag names in angle brackets that need to be removed.  Also the default padding is different in c# from java and has to be the same.

Comment: what you elaborate more ? i need to remove <> </> from the privateKey? if its different how do it do it? if i use a public website to check private key and outputs it works correctly like this one https://8gwifi.org/rsafunctions.jsp .

Comment: The website for key doesn't have the tags.  The site may just be removing the tags without letting you know.  The key that is used for encryption has to be the same as the key for decryption and padding has to be the same.  Padding adds random characters to end of key so it is fixed size (like 1024) and makes it harder to hack.  You can usually tell if a key is padded by counting the number of characters and see if standard value like 2048.  A non padded key will be an odd number like 2123,